# Can't access Spring server from other devices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, networking

I have a website, which has a back end and shows a list of Topics. The back end is written in Spring, and H2 as the database. The database is saved in a file on my PC.

Here's my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:C:/Projects/database/dbname
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2console
```

When I access the website from the PC where the Spring server is hosted, my list of Topics is loaded in just fine and everything works, but when I try to access the site from other devices in my LAN I get an error in the Chrome console: `GET net:ERR_CONNECTION-REFUSED`

and also: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network error`

Comment: You probably have a firewall blocking port 8080 from being accessed outside your computer.

Comment: Also some servers only listen on the loopback interface, I mean, only IP addresses `127.0.0.1` or `::1` So please check that it works with your network(not local) IP address in your browser, and the browser from another PC or Mobile device in the same network. E.g. if your machine has local IP `192.168.1.13`, check that `192.168.1.13:8080` is accessible from your and other machine

Comment: @BorisTreukhov I was using 127.0.0.1, I'm so dumb, thanks a lot!!!